# How to give cel shading material in SceneKit?

Tags: shader, scenekit, shading

I would like to know if it is possible to apply a cel shading effect in SceneKit? When I apply a toon material effect in a 3D app it is never transmitted to SceneKit... so is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information on this topic?